# Is there a python library that would return the 'Etc/GMT+x' timezone string from the country based timezone string?

Tags: python, timestamp

I am asking whether there exists a python library which either converts a country based time-zone string to the corresponding GMT offset based time-zone string. For example, 'America/Los Angeles' would be converted to 'Etc/GMT+8'. Alternatively, is there a python library that can yield 'Etc/GMT+8' timezone from latitude and longitude of a location in Los Angeles, CA ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (note that you will need to throttle your `geopy` requests to avoid breaching the API limit)

```
from geopy import geocoders
g = geocoders.GoogleV3()
place, (lat, lng) = g.geocode('New York')
tz = g.timezone((lat, lng))
```

Which I think gives what you are after

```
In [19]: place, tz
Out[19]: (u'New York, NY, USA', <DstTzInfo 'America/New_York' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)
```

Alternative methods of getting the Lat/Lon into a timezone can be found here:

- [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/4013571)

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is the DST independent timezone. In your case the desired answer would be 'Etc/GMT+5' for New York.